# High volume inserts for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for some advice on how to implement a process for mass inserts, like to the tune of 400 records per second. The data is coming from an outside real time trigger and the app will get notified when a data change happens. When that data change happens, I need to consume it.

I've looked at several different implementations for doing batch processing including using datatables/sqlbulkcopy or writing to csv and consuming.

What can you recommend?

Comment: 400 distinct calls per second? Or one batch of 400 rows needs to be inserted per second?

Comment: Where are the 400 inserts generated from? Have you just tried inserting them directly? Why do you need to do it in batch?

Comment: Buffer `n` records and then use `SqlBulkCopy` or a table valued parameter.

Comment: I'm getting 400 distinct calls per second. I don't need to batch them, I was thinking it would be optimum to batch up records together - do one call to the db and close connection. I have tried inserting them directly and that works ok, it seems like there's a better option. I was wondering what others have done and what they can recommend.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  would love to see how you use buffer.  Please elaborate or post an answer, thx.

Comment: The one thing I'll caution about buffering requests (or another variant thereof) would just be what happens if an error occurs or your application crashes or something. Just something to bear in mind as you think about the durability in such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

400 inserts per second doesn't feel like it should present any major challenge. It depends on what you're inserting, if there are any indexes which could have page splits due to inserts, and if you have any extra logic going on during your insert proc or script.

If you want to insert them one by one, I would recommend just building a barebones stored procedure which does a simple insert of it's parameters into a staging table with no indexes, constraints, anything. That will allow you to *very* quickly get the data into the database, and you can have a separate process come through every minute or something and work off the rows in batches.

Alternatively, you could have your application store up records until you reach a certain number, and then insert them into the database with a proc using a table-valued parameter. Then you'll only have one insert of however many rows you chose to batch up. The cost of that should be pretty trivial. Do note however that if your application crashes before it's inserted enough rows, those will be lost.

SqlBulkCopy is a powerful tool, but as the name suggests, it's built more for bulk loading of tables. If you have a constant stream of insert requests coming in, I would *not* recommend using it to load up your data. That might be a good approach if you want to batch up a LOT of requests to load all at once, but not as a recurring and frequent activity.

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty well for me.  I can't guarantee you 400 per sec tho:

```
    private async Task BulkInsert(string tableName, DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt == null)
            return;

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy("./sqlserver..."))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
            await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dt);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this as well and I hit my memory limit very quickly. Although, the server is in the process of being upgraded (CPUs and RAM) - it might be ok. Datatables seem to be expensive.